# Injecting a SignalR hub using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, signalr, simple-injector

I've seen a few examples where a custom hub activator is registered, e.g. `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IHubActivator), () => new SimpleInjectorHubActivator(container));`. If I understand it correctly it allows for DI inside hubs.

I simply want to inject hubs directly in to my controllers, what would be the correct approach? Should I use `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>()`, register it as singelton and inject it as IHubContext?

Comment: Are you using `SignalR` in asp .net core? If so why aren't you using the DI-system that ships with asp? If not, where and how are you using it?

Comment: @Joelius It's regular asp.net with a web api